# Koa js Cannot find module 'koa-bodyparser' Internal Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, body-parser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xX0g.png)

```
const Koa = require('Koa');

const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');

const productRoutes = require('../routes/products.routes');

const app = new Koa();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(productRoutes.routes()).use(productRoutes.allowedMethods());

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Application is running on the port 3000");
```

Comment: Have you actually installed `koa-bodyparser`?

Comment: Yes. And there is another error " node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
"